# what is the result

Tags: sql, sql-server

The following query gives the output as 123.5

```
SELECT STR(123.45, 6, 1);  
GO
```

But.. The following query gives the output as 123.3

```
SELECT STR(123.35, 6, 1);  
GO
```

Why it is not giving the result as 123.4 ?

```
SELECT STR(123.45, 6, 1);  
GO

SELECT STR(123.35, 6, 1);  
GO
```

The following query gives the output as 123.3

```
SELECT STR(123.35, 6, 1);  
GO
```

Why it is not giving the result as 123.4 ?

Comment: What DBMS are you using?

Comment: Floating point arithmetic is not exact, and this is the explanation for what you are seeing possibly.

Comment: MS SQL is the DBMS

Comment: *"MS SQL is the DBMS "* the tag sql is not meant for SQL Server (MSSQL) on this website @Kamakshi the sql tag is meant for ANSI/ISO standard SQL..

Comment: Thank you @ Tim Biegeleisen

Comment: same issue by `123.85`, result `123.8`

Comment: But I'm getting the result for select str(123.354,6,1)  as 123.4... So whether floating point arithmetic precision is the only reason @TimBiegeleisen

Comment: Oh.. Okok.. Thank you @RaymondNijland

Comment: Look at the results of `SELECT CAST(CAST(123.45 AS FLOAT) AS DECIMAL(38,35)), CAST(CAST(123.35 AS FLOAT) AS DECIMAL(38,35))` - which are `123.45000000000000284217094304040074348` and `123.34999999999999431565811391919851303`

Comment: @Kamakshi this isn't a matter of floating point precision. You asked for only 1 decimal digit and `STR` uses a *different* rounding strategy than `ROUND`. Use `FORMAT` for consistent rounding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Long story short, use FORMAT instead of STR, only to format strings. There is an inconsistency here indeed.

`STR` is [rounding half to odd](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding#Round_half_to_odd) which is an .... odd behavior. The more common approach is [round half to even](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding#Round_half_to_even), also known as Banker's rounding. Both strategies minimize the aggregated rounding error.

That's why

```
SELECT STR(123.45, 6, 1),STR(123.35, 6, 1);
```

Returns

```
 123.5   123.3
```

`STR` is *not* a rounding function though, it's a string formatting function. The strings it produces aren't meant to be added. What's more, T-SQL's `ROUND` function rounds *away from zero*  and

```
SELECT round(123.45,1), round(123.35,1);
```

Produces

```
123.50  123.40
```

Oracle, PostgreSQL and MySQL's ROUND behave the same way, rounding away from zero. I suspect this is part of the standard but I haven't found a relevant link yet.

The [FORMAT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/format-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) is far more powerful. It uses the same format strings as .NET and rounds away from zero.

```
SELECT FORMAT(123.45, 'n1'), FORMAT(123.35, 'n1');
```

Produces

```
123.5   123.4
```

Comment: Can you explain why `123.45` becomes `123.5` while `123.35` becomes `123.3`?  I can't think of a reason, other than floating point arithmetic.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen - yes your explanation is correct. neither number can be represented exactly as a floating point number. `123.45` is represented as a number a bit over and `123.35` as a number a bit under - hence difference in treatment

Answer (score 3):

From the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/str-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) for SQL Server's `STR` function:

> [the first parameter] Is an expression of approximate numeric (float) data type with a decimal point.

From my local testing, even if I pass in a `DECIMAL` value, the imprecision you are seeing continues, and the input parameter still gets treated as a float. 
 That is:

```
SELECT STR(CAST(123.45 AS DECIMAL(10,2)), 6, 1)
```

still returns `123.5`.

If you want to truncate a numerical value exactly in SQL Server, then just try casting to a `DECIMAL` type, e.g.

```
SELECT CAST(123.45 AS DECIMAL(10,1))
```

returns `123.4` as you would expect.